# MariaDB/Galera Cluster with 3 nodes - Change ENGINE from MyISAM to InnoDB without crash

Tags: replication, mariadb, myisam, galera, crash

We have tables with MyISAM. The are out of sync, the number of records is different on each cluster node

```
> select table_schema, table_name from tables where ENGINE = 'MyISAM' and table_schema != 'mysql';
+--------------+------------+
| table_schema | table_name |
+--------------+------------+
| nrmtz       | tablename1  |
| nrmwetr   | tablename1  |
| nrmrzhredr  | tablename1  |
| nrmesfw     | tablename1  |
| sdtz        | tablename1  |
| sdwetr    | tablename1  |
| sdrzhredr   | tablename1  |
| sdesfw      | tablename1  |
| smtz        | tablename1  |
| smwetr    | tablename1  |
| smrzhredr   | tablename1  |
| smesfw      | tablename1  |
+--------------+------------+
12 rows in set (0.02 sec)

> desc tablename1;
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| migration_id | bigint(20) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

   -> ;
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table     | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| gomigrate | CREATE TABLE `tablename1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `migration_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `migration_id` (`migration_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Our version (we can't upgrade easy) and cluster status

```
> select VERSION();
+----------------------+
| VERSION()            |
+----------------------+
| 5.5.41-MariaDB-wsrep |
+----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

> show status like '%wsrep%';
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                           |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | 927d368c-b92d-11e5-bb07-2647ef235310            |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 5                                               |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 5592805                                         |
| wsrep_replicated             | 4287245                                         |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 2067046243                                      |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 12903900                                        |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 201838365                                       |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 1590824198                                      |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                               |
| wsrep_received               | 1350734                                         |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 676386342                                       |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 4285656                                         |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 1                                               |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                               |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                               |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000431                                        |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                               |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.013302                                        |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 5353930                                         |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                               |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                        |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                               |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                               |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 12.204780                                       |
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.034583                                        |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                        |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 1.036009                                        |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                        |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                        |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 1.001590                                        |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                               |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                          |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 23                                              |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                               |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.072367                                        |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 192.168.5.32:3306,192.168.5.31:3306,192.168.5.33:3306 |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 7                                               |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                               |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | 927d368c-b92d-11e5-bb07-2647ef235310            |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                         |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                              |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                               |
| wsrep_local_index            | 1                                               |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                          |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>               |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 3.5(rXXXX)                                      |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                              |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                               |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
48 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need the tables to be InnoDB and in sync. Those two statements crashing.

```
CREATE TABLE test ENGINE=InnoDB SELECT * FROM nrmtz.tablename1;

ALTER TABLE tablename1 ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Are there other ways doing it without crash?

Comment: Maybe you could dump the table, change the engine in the dump and reimport it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the tables to be InnoDB and in sync. Those two statements crashing.

Does it crash with a stack trace in the server logs? Could you share it here? I tried the above two commands on a 2-node MariaDB-5.5.47 cluster and it worked as expected.

As @jkavalik suggested, you could do something like the following :

1. Create a new INNODB table with the same definition. This table gets replicated to other nodes.
2. Dump data from the old table into a file `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE ...`
3. Reload data from the file into the new table `LOAD DATA INFILE ... [REPLACE|IGNORE] ...`. The inserted records also get replicated to other nodes.
4. Repeat 2-3 on other nodes.
5. Rename table created in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

MyISAM support in galera is *cough* beta at best.

The best thing to do is:
mysqldump ... -T  db table_name > dump.sql  (this will make a .sql and .txt file)
drop the myisam table
edit the .sql file and change ENGINE=MYISAM to ENGINE=INNODB
LOAD DATA INFILE 'table.txt' INTO TABLE table_name;

Do this on whatever node that you want to treat as the "source of truth".

If you want a consistent table with records from all nodes, then do the above, then use sort to sort the tables (using the PK, ideally an auto-increment) removing the duplicates, then import the .txt with records from all tables.